# not able to access the nested Json data

Tags: angularjs, json

[code on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tNiD60Vxfp3WxTjPXNqM?p=preview) So my task is to display a certain list of markets and my aim is to choose one market name in the option so I can view its details. Also, incase that market has any other submarkets, I can view them too. I'm coding with angularjs, have a nested json data and using ui-router to navigate through different states (if 1st state displays the main market, next will display either its details or its submarkets). The first state's just fine. But I am not able to find out the correct logic to display appropriate data on the next state. Here's what I've done:

```
app.controller('mktctrl', function($scope,$state){
$scope.mrData={
"supermkt":[ 
              { "id":10,
                "name":"val1",
                "submkt":[
                           { "sid":101,
                             "sname":"val1.1",
                              ... ,
                             "submkt":[
                                        { "sid":1011,
                                          "sname":"val1.1.1",
                                           ...
                                        },
                                        { "sid":1012,
                                          "sname":"val1.1.2",
                                           ...
                                        }
                                       ]
                            },
                            { "sid":102,
                              "sname":"val1.2",
                              ...
                            }
                          ],
               "supermkt":[
                            { "id":103,
                              "name":"val1.3",
                              "submkt":[
                                         {....}
                                       ]
                            }
                           ]
              },
              { "id":11,
                "name":"val2",
                 ....
              }
           ] 
    };


  $scope.mktname=[];/*stores main top level market*/
  angular.forEach($scope.mrData.supermkt,function(mar){
  $scope.mktname.push(mar);
  });

  });
```

/* now what appears in the first state is a list like

val1,

val2..

what I want is, when I click on one of these (i used ui-sref) say "val1", Im taken to another state that displays ONLY the details or name of the "submkt" or "supermkt" under "val1" and so on. I tried this:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.mktname.length;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<$scope.mktname[i].submkt.length<0;j++)
  $scope.submktname.push($scope.mktname[i].submkt[j]);
}
```

The above showed an error : "undefined not an object(evaluating j)" (how am I suppose to correctly access these subarrays)
Also, when I wrote this code, even the first state wouldn't display and my app page is completely blank.
For I also figured that the above logic would iterate through all the objects in mktname array and may store the "submkt" details of all (val1,val2,..) in submktname, I'm not able to figure out the appropriate logic. Some help with detailed explanation would help a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked json, not all subnodes are of type array. e.g. `$scope.mktname[1]` is of type object and not of array.

So you must check whether the node is of type object first and then iterate in lop as like below, Updated with snippest

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.mrData = {
    "supermkt": [{
      "id": 10,
      "name": "val1",
      "submkt": [{
        "sid": 101,
        "sname": "val1.1",
        "submkt": [{
          "sid": 1011,
          "sname": "val1.1.1",
        }, {
          "sid": 1012,
          "sname": "val1.1.2",
        }]
      }, {
        "sid": 102,
        "sname": "val1.2",
      }],
      "supermkt": [{
        "id": 103,
        "name": "val1.3",
        "submkt": [{
          "sid": 1011,
          "sname": "val1.1.1",
        }, {
          "sid": 1012,
          "sname": "val1.1.2",
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "val2",
    }]
  };

  $scope.mktname = []; /*stores main top level market*/
  $scope.submktname = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.mrData.supermkt, function(mar) {
    $scope.mktname.push(mar);
  });
  


  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mktname.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.mktname[i]);
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call($scope.mktname[i].submkt));
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call($scope.mktname[i].submkt) === '[object Array]') {
      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.mktname[i].submkt.length ; j++) {

        $scope.submktname.push($scope.mktname[i].submkt[j]);
      }
    }
  }


});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" ></script>

 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p> {{submktname | json}}!</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: There's no error now. But no still no data is displayed. where can i see if my data has been stored at all.

Comment: Have added snippest to help with, there were problem in inner for loop  condition as well

Comment: My problem is still not solved. As i said this code is accessing the submkt details only not the "supermkt" detail which is also a part of sub detail under val1. Also, it's taking sub details of all the super markets (val1,val2) and puts them together in submktname. Im not able to find the exact logic.

Comment: Could you please add jsfiddler/plunker to point out exact problem?

Comment: Lot of things were not workign in plunker given, I simplified [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/y1UOKM53VjbuAvYEwyai?p=preview) without UI router

Comment: Yeah..I didn't understand y it would not work that way. Thanks. What I was pointing out to was the output in submarket details. You may see that val1.1 val1.2 are displayed but not val1.3 ...instead val2.1 gets displayed. val2.1 is not the submarket of val1